# How to extract complete event using regex in one capturing group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have following events from which I am trying to extract "loc" field

```
loc=/abc/flows/timespan/2021-08-10T11:35:00+00:00_2021-08-10T12:35:00+00:00/ip_initiate/10.101.10.20/data.ext

loc=\"{\"type\":1,\"namespace\":\"flows\",\"appIds\":\"10,11,12\",\"path_bar\":\"[\\\"ip_initiate=10.1.120.11\\\"]\",\"2021-08-10T11:35:00+00:00_2021-08-10T12:35:00+00:00\\/ip_initiate\\/10.1.120.11\\/http_code\\/200\",\"restrict\":null}\"", day=xyz

loc=\"{\"type\":1,\"namespace\":\"flows\",\"appIds\":\"10,11,12\",\"path_bar\":\"[\\\"ip_initiate=10.1.120.11\\\"]\",\"2021-08-10T11:35:00+00:00_2021-08-10T12:35:00+00:00\\/ip_initiate\\/10.1.120.11\\/http_code\\/200\",\"restrict\":null}\"", ip=10.10.10.10

loc=\"/timespan/2021-09-12T14:21:00/ip_responder/10.10.10.10/,country=xyz,dns=example.com,http:code=2548:111:0:0:0:0:182.25.236.2:10\"
```

I am able to extract it successfully with below regex using multiple capturing groups -

```
    (loc=(.*),\s)|(loc=(.*?)$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/dyWR2g/1

I wanted to know whether or not it will be possible to extract the complete "loc" field in just one group and if yes, then what changes will I need to make in my above regex.

Basically I don't want the pipe(|)in my regex.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just `loc=.*$`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the ,\s and the $ in its own group separated by | if you dont want different group numbers.

The value of loc is now in capture group 1.

```
loc=(.*?)(?:,\s|$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `loc=` Match literally
- `(.*?)` Capture group 1, match as least as possible
- `(?:,\s|$)` Non capture group, match either , and a whitespace char or end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kpfEyo/1)

Without the | char at all, you could use

```
loc=((?:(?!\s,).)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/klTS71/1)

Comment: Thats just perfect!! Thanks a lot:)

Comment: And since we are on the topic do you mind helping me in removing all the back slashes and double qoutes from the event  conn=\"pass-1001\"" . I am currently trying something with replace like (conn,"\\\\(.)","") but it is not removing the last double quotes, so the result I am getting are conn=pass-1001" .

Comment: @ak0252 Removing 1 or more backslashes followed by a double colon `\\+"` and replace with an empty space. Removing any backslash or double quote, you can use a character class and repeat it 1 or more times to do a single replacement with an empty string `[\\"]+` See https://regex101.com/r/7udium/1